# TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'AgoraRTM.prefix')

Tags: android, react-native, agora.io

i am making a chat app and using [agora rtm messaging package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/agora-react-native-rtm), I used their [exampe](https://github.com/AgoraIO/agora-react-native-rtm/tree/master/example)
and I am getting this error *TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'AgoraRTM.prefix')* I saw the package and found that this AgoraRTM is coming from the native code written for the package and I am not familiar with native swift or java code. Can anyone give me the solution and tell me what's wrong and how I can solve this error.

Answer (score -1):

in my case of agora-rn-uikit library
I installed this library and it solved my error
here is link

https://www.npmjs.com/package/agora-react-native-rtm

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32597177)